# Cannot build YugabyteDB with clang12 in Alma Linux 8.5

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Debug build does not seem to be working in the clang12 based build:

```
./yb_build.sh debug --sj
```

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../../tests-integration-tests/cdc_service-int-test
[100%] Built target cdc_service-int-test
make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2

real    0m28.279s
user    4m4.235s
sys    0m25.477s
[2022-02-26T15:52:32 yb_build.sh:466 run_cxx_build] C++ build finished with exit code 2 (build type: debug, compiler: clang12). Timing information is available above.

==========================================================================================
YUGABYTE BUILD SUMMARY
==========================================================================================
Build type                       : debug
C/C++ compiler                   : clang12
Build architecture               : x86_64
Build directory                  : /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic
Third-party dir                  : /opt/yb-build/thirdparty/yugabyte-db-thirdparty-v20211222064150-dd4872fe56-almalinux8-x86_64-clang12
C++ compilation time             : 28 seconds
Exit code                        : 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
doing
./yb_build.sh debug --clang12 --sj
also results in an error
...
[m-1] In YugabyteDB, setting LC_COLLATE to C and all other locale settings to en_US.UTF-8 by default. Locale support will be enhanced as part of addressing https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/1557
[m-1] initdb: invalid locale name "en_US.UTF-8"
[m-1] I0226 15:54:20.630203 15811 pg_wrapper.cc:521] initdb took 124 ms
[m-1] E0226 15:54:20.630272 15811 pg_wrapper.cc:525] initdb failed: Runtime error (yb/yql/pgwrapper/pg_wrapper.cc:467): /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic/postgres/bin/initdb failed with exit code 1
[m-1] E0226 15:54:20.630429 15811 catalog_manager.cc:7776] initdb failed: Runtime error (yb/yql/pgwrapper/pg_wrapper.cc:467): /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic/postgres/bin/initdb failed with exit code 1
E0226 15:54:21.075644 15749 external_mini_cluster.cc:1247] master reported an initdb error: Runtime error (yb/yql/pgwrapper/pg_wrapper.cc:467): /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic/postgres/bin/initdb failed with exit code 1
/yb-source/src/yb/yql/pgwrapper/pg_wrapper_test_base.cc:58: Failure
Failed
Bad status: Runtime error (yb/integration-tests/external_mini_cluster.cc:1248): Failed to start masters.: initdb failed: Runtime error (yb/yql/pgwrapper/pg_wrapper.cc:467): /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic/postgres/bin/initdb failed with exit code 1
[m-1] W0226 15:54:21.096375 15815 catalog_manager.cc:2084] Tablespace refresh task failed with error Internal error (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:1929): pg_tablespace table info not found
Test failure stack trace:
/yb-source/src/yb/yql/pgwrapper/pg_wrapper_test_base.cc:58:                                             @     0x7f2962b044e9  yb::pgwrapper::PgWrapperTestBase::SetUp()
/yb-source/src/yb/yql/pgwrapper/create_initial_sys_catalog_snapshot.cc:29:                              @           0x404d94  yb::pgwrapper::CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshotTest::SetUp()
I0226 15:54:21.706461 15749 external_mini_cluster.cc:2206] { daemon_id: m-1 bound_rpc: :0 } Starting Shutdown()
I0226 15:54:21.706606 15749 external_mini_cluster.cc:2249] Killing /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic/tests-pgwrapper/../bin/yb-master with pid 15756 with SIGKILL
I0226 15:54:21.719123 15749 test_util.cc:94] -----------------------------------------------
I0226 15:54:21.719149 15749 test_util.cc:95] Had fatal failures, leaving test files at /tmp/yb_test.tmp.32433.7631.5669.pid15685/create_initial_sys_catalog_snapshot.CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshotTest.CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshot.1645890856672495-15749
[  FAILED  ] CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshotTest.CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshot (5016 ms)
[----------] 1 test from CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshotTest (5016 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (5016 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshotTest.CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshot

 1 FAILED TEST
I0226 15:54:21.751582 15748 run-with-timeout.cc:198] subprocess.Wait finished, waitpid() returned 256
...
[postprocess_test_result.py:246] 2022-02-26 15:54:22,577 INFO: Wrote JSON test report file: /yb-source/build/debug-clang12-dynamic/yb-test-logs/tests-pgwrapper__create_initial_sys_catalog_snapshot/CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshotTest_CreateInitialSysCatalogSnapshot_test_report.json
(end of standard error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/yb-source/python/yb/gen_initial_sys_catalog_snapshot.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "/yb-source/python/yb/gen_initial_sys_catalog_snapshot.py", line 74, in main
    raise RuntimeError("initdb failed in %.1f sec" % elapsed_time_sec)
RuntimeError: initdb failed in 6.4 sec
make[2]: *** [src/yb/yql/pgwrapper/CMakeFiles/initial_sys_catalog_snapshot.dir/build.make:70: src/yb/yql/pgwrapper/CMakeFiles/initial_sys_catalog_snapshot] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:51929: src/yb/yql/pgwrapper/CMakeFiles/initial_sys_catalog_snapshot.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
```

This happens in Alma Linux 8.5. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some additional packages and it should work:

```
dnf install langpacks-en glibc-all-langpacks -y
```